# Javascript variable used in firefox extension

Tags: javascript, variables, firefox-addon, xul

**I have:** I would like to learn about Firefox extensions, so I downloaded the zip file containing the "Hello World" example from http://kb.mozillazine.org/Getting_started_with_extension_development.

In hello.xul I have:

```
<hbox align="center">
<description flex="1">text in box</description>
</hbox>
```

(gives a pop-up box with the text "text in box")

In overlay.js I have:

```
var HelloWorld = {
  onLoad: function() {
    // initialization code
    this.initialized = true;
  },

  onMenuItemCommand: function() {
    window.open("chrome://helloworld/content/hello.xul", "", "chrome");
    var a = "text I want in box";
  }
};

window.addEventListener("load", function(e) { HelloWorld.onLoad(e); }, false);
```

**Question**: How to I use the variable a in the javascript file in so that the content of that variable is what is "printed" in the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.openDialog#Passing_extra_parameters_to_the_dialog

You should use parameters to pass value from one window to another window`(Dialog Concept)`.

This provides a simple way to pass values across xul files.

For your problem you can do something like this in the xxx.xul. This will open `hello.xul` along with the extra parameter returnValues:

```
var returnValues = { out: null };
window.openDialog("hello.xul", "tree", "modal", returnValues);
```

Note modal is a must.

Next in your xxx.xul, store all the values (lets call it y) that you want to pass to `hello.xul` as below:

```
window.arguments[0].out = y
```

Note `window.argument[0]` refers to returnValues

Now you can access the values of y (which is the names of the labels in your case) in `hello.xul` as follows:

```
var labels = returnValues.out;
```

Basically,

You pass a parameter to the child window at the time of opening it.

Then in the child window, fill the parameter with the values that wish to pass back to the parent window and then close the child window.

Now back in the parent window you can access the parameter that you passed to the child and it contains information updated by the child window.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the parameters to new window. An example is shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Dialogs_and_Prompts#Passing_arguments_and_displaying_a_dialog)